# Set default value for all undefined jinja2 variables in a Flask template

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, jinja2, amadeus

I have a flask app that queries the Amadeus self-service API for flight information. Typically this works well. The API returns JSON of itineraries, their segments, and dictionaries of city, airline, aircraft codes. My results template iterates through the itineraries and their segments and uses the included dictionaries to look up codes.

But occasionally the JSON is malformed or missing data and that completely breaks rendering of the html, resulting in a 500 error. Here is the most recent example.

The relevant code from my template:

**live_results.html**

```
<p> {{ flights.dictionaries.carriers[segment.carrierCode].title() }}&nbsp;&nbsp;Flight {{ segment.number }}
   <br><span class="w3-text-gray">{{ flights.dictionaries.aircraft[segment.aircraft.code].title() }}
   </span></p>
```

For some of the flight segments, `flights.dictionaries.aircraft` was missing a key for the aircraft code (in this example '32Q'). The resulting error from my server log:

```
Exception on /live_results [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  
File "/home/SteveZ/dragonfly/fly_app/routes.py", line 313, in live_results
    code_dict=code_dict
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  
File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  
File "/home/SteveZ/dragonfly/fly_app/templates/live_results.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
  
File "/home/SteveZ/dragonfly/fly_app/templates/base.html", line 42, in top-level template code
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  
File "/home/SteveZ/dragonfly/fly_app/templates/live_results.html", line 104, in block "content"
    <br><span class="w3-text-gray">{{ flights.dictionaries.aircraft[segment.aircraft.code].title() }}

File "/home/SteveZ/.virtualenvs/WOF_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 471, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dict object' has no attribute '32Q'
```

I fixed this specific case by setting a jinja2 default for the affected variables. But that amounts to reacting after the errors.

I would like to immunize my code against errors like this by setting all undefined variables to a default string value (either an empty string or 'Undefined'). Is there a way to do that? Perhaps with Flask.jinja_env or in how flask parses JSON?

Finally, if handling of these errors is possible, is there a way to do that *and* log when they occur?

Comment: i would suggest you "sanitizing" the `json` object in your `view` function **before** passing it to `jinja2` to render template.  Browse the object and when you find some thing missing or invalid then force it to defaults.

Comment: @cizario Thanks. I thought of that, but template rendering needs to iterate over multiple itineraries and segments within itineraries. So I could not simply pass values as literal variables in render_template(name, **kwargs). I could write a function that does what I need  and pass the function to render_template. Does that make sense?